# How do I use this enum in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

**1) I converted this Swift enum from this:**

```
public enum TimeZone {
    case Local, UTC
}
```

**into this:**

```
@interface DateFormat : NSObject

@property enum TimeZone {Local, UTC};


+ (instancetype) ISODateFormat: (NSString *) isoFormat;
+ (instancetype) DotNetDateFormat;
+ (instancetype) RSSDateFormat;
+ (instancetype) AltRSSDateFormat;
+ (instancetype) CustomDateFormat: (NSString *) formatString;

@property (readonly) NSString *dateFormatType;
@property (readonly) NSString *formatDetails;


@end
```

---

**2) Now I need to convert this:**

```
func toString(format format: DateFormat, timeZone: TimeZone = .Local) -> String
{
    var dateFormat: String
    let zone: NSTimeZone

    switch format {

        case .DotNet:
            let offset = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone().secondsFromGMT / 3600
            let nowMillis = 1000 * self.timeIntervalSince1970
            return  "/Date(\(nowMillis)\(offset))/"

        case .ISO8601(let isoFormat):
            dateFormat = (isoFormat != nil) ? isoFormat!.rawValue : ISO8601Format.DateTimeMilliSec.rawValue
            zone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

        case .RSS:
            dateFormat = RSSFormat
            zone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

        case .AltRSS:
            dateFormat = AltRSSFormat
            zone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

        case .Custom(let string):

            switch timeZone {
                case .Local:
                    zone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
                case .UTC:
                    zone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
            }
            dateFormat = string
    }

    let formatter = NSDate.formatter(format: dateFormat, timeZone: zone)
    return formatter.stringFromDate(self)
}
```

---

**3) Here's what I converted so far:**

```
    - (NSString *) toString: (DateFormat *) format : (DateFormat *) timeZone{
        NSString *dateFormat;
        NSTimeZone *zone;
        if([format.dateFormatType compare: DotNetDateFormatType] == NSOrderedSame) {
            NSInteger offset = [[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] secondsFromGMT] / 3600;
            NSInteger nowMillis = 1000 * self.timeIntervalSince1970;
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Date(%ld%ld)/", (long)nowMillis, (long)offset];
        }
        else if([format.dateFormatType compare: ISO8601DateFormatType] == NSOrderedSame) {
            NSString *isoFormat = ISO8601DateFormatType;
            dateFormat =  (isoFormat != nil) ? isoFormat : ISOFormatDateTimeMilliSec;
        }
        else if([format.dateFormatType compare: RSSDateFormatType] == NSOrderedSame) {
            dateFormat = RSSDateFormatType;
        }
        else if([format.dateFormatType compare: AltRSSDateFormatType] == NSOrderedSame) {
            dateFormat = AltRSSDateFormatType;
        }
        else if([format.dateFormatType compare: CustomDateFormatType] == NSOrderedSame) {
            NSString *string = CustomDateFormatType;
            dateFormat = string;
        }
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDate formatter : dateFormat : [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] : [NSLocale currentLocale]];
        return [formatter stringFromDate:(self)];
    }
```

---

**PROBLEM:**

I have trouble including the TimeZone enum in there. All behaviour that I converted works fine, I just need to implement the enum. Any ideas?

Comment: use `isEqualToString:` to compare strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of inline `enum` declaration:

```
@property enum TimeZone {Local, UTC};
```

Declare it outside the `@interface` as

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, TimeZone) {
   kTimeZoneLocal = 0,
   kTimeZoneUTC
};
```

(names are needed to prevent conflict, default value of zero for the first value is common).

Then the property:

```
@property (nonatomic) TimeZone timezone;
```

The method header should be something like this:

```
- (NSString *)toStringWithFormat:(DateFormat *)format andTimeZone:(TimeZone)timeZone {
```

and just use `kTimeZoneLocal` instead of every `.Local` and `kTimeZoneUTC` instead of every `.UTC`.

Comment: @Coder1000 Please, at least attempt to search first. If you are translating code into Obj-C, you should at least learn the basic syntax.

Comment: The Class reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/ tells me it's: `timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT`